# Can a ship in the Drift communicate with someone outside the Drift?

Tags: starfinder

Traveling between worlds in the system takes 1d6+2 Days (Core pg 291) while system wide communication takes 1d6-1 Hours (Core pg. 430).

Is there any reason a ship travelling in the Drift for 3-8 days can't communicate with someone on a planet in that system, on a non-drifting ship, or even with a ship that is also drifting with messages taking 0-5 hours to travel between communication arrays?

By RAW, I can't find anything limiting it, but I'm wondering if I've missed some rule that communications don't function while in the Drift.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it can. In fact, all long-range communications happen through the Drift

Otherwise, they would take *far* longer to reach anywhere, as they would travel using the *Speed of Light* instead of going through a dimentional shortcut. This is mentioned only briefly in the core rulebook :

> **Interstellar communication**
>
> Like system-wide communication, interstellar communication uses **Drift beacons** to relay the information, and can theoretically transmit to an unlimited distance. Due to the restrictions of travel through the Drift, interstellar **communication takes as long as it would take a spaceship to travel the same distance**.

Since you're using Drift beacons to cross the distance anyway, it should work just as well if the signal originates in the Drift.

Comment: This is good info, but seems to require a bit of extrapolation to answer the question as asked. Could you add a tl;dr with a firm yes or no?

Comment: Im not extrapolating anything. The OP apparently didn't know about Drift Beacons, and I just pointed that those are a thing. The question is answered.

Comment: I made an edit to show what I'm talking about. To me, that's much clearer, especially if you're just skimming. If you object, you can of course revert.